# C++ openCV video to panorama

Tags: c++, opencv, 360-panorama

I'm trying to create panorama out of a video by stitching frame n-1 with frame n.
My problem is that after (around 20 frames) the right side of the picture gets very blurry and I don't know what to do with it.

main:

```
  frames = getVideoFrames();
  stichPair(frames[1], frames[0], panorama[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        stichPair(frames[i], panorama[i - 2], panorama[i - 1]);
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    cvNamedWindow(windowsName1, 1);
    on_trackbar(index, 0);
    createTrackbar("MyTrackbar:", windowsName1, &index, SIZE - 2, on_trackbar);
```

stichPair:

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> brisk = BRISK::create(20, 3, 1.0f);
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = BFMatcher::create("BruteForce-Hamming");
// find features
    brisk->detect(leftImage, keypoints_1);
    brisk->detect(rightImage, keypoints_2);
    brisk->compute(leftImage, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
    brisk->compute(rightImage, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);

    // Find two nearest matches
    matcher->knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 2);

    //filter bad matches
    const float ratio = 0.6;
    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (matches[i][0].distance / matches[i][1].distance < ratio)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        leftImage_matchedKPs.push_back(keypoints_1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        rightImage_matchedKPs.push_back(keypoints_2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    H = findHomography(Mat(rightImage_matchedKPs), Mat(leftImage_matchedKPs), RANSAC, 5);
    warpPerspective(rightImage, rightImageWarped, H, Size(4000, 1280)); // fixed size

    panorama = rightImageWarped.clone();
    roi = Mat(panorama, Rect(0, 0, leftImage.cols, leftImage.rows));
    leftImage.copyTo(roi);
}
```

[after 20 frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiHd9.jpg)

[after 40 frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7ucU.jpg)

Comment: the blurriness comes from the scale factor of the image. The scaling comes from some inevitable drift which either results from small errors in the registration or from the fact that you are trying to construct a 3D scene on the 2D image. The perspective homographies used in stitching are only correct for a planar scene, or if the camera center is changed by pure rotation.

Comment: you could try to use INTER_CUBIC or INTER_LANCZOS4 in warpPerspective, but the documentation only talks about INTER_LINEAR and INTER_NEAREST, so maybe the others don't exist ist warping...

Comment: same results with INTER_CUBIC or INTER_LANCZOS4

Comment: @user2809151 was this ever resolved?